# Configuring Dovecot to Authenticate Against LDAP Without Access to the Password Field

Tags: ldap, authentication, dovecot

We have an LDAP server that everyone authenticates against. I need to configure Dovecot to authenticate against it, however I'm running into a major issue.

As per [the documentation](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/PasswordLookups), Dovecot requires access to the password field in order to do authentication:

> Normally LDAP server doesn't give anyone access to users' passwords, so you'll need to create an administrator account that has access to the userPassword field.

Due to the security policies, there is no way that this is happening. Is there a way to bypass this requirement? Eg just send the password to LDAP and look for a 'passed/failed' reply?

OS: Centos 6 x86_64
Dovecot: 2.0.9-22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you linked named the alternative on the very top: [Authentication binds](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/AuthBinds). With this, you just need `auth` ACLs for the password field in LDAP and Dovecot does essentially exactly what you want to do.

Note that having `auth` access rights for this is absolutely mandatory and if your security policy also forbids that, you need to scrap it because it doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Yeah, this turned out to be the correct solution. I did initially try using this but was getting rather confusing error messages so I sort of... forgot about this option. I reimplemented it and fixed the errors I was getting and everything is now working :)